# ¿Cómo puedo borrar una fila desde la misma tabla?

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, bootstrap-4

Hola chicos estoy desarrollando una app, la idea es que borre la fila desde la misma tabla, dándole al botón eliminar en este caso el trash, pero no consigo hacerlo muestro la tabla y la fila.

[image: Tabla de la base de datos]

[image: Foto de la aplicación]

```
<?php
session_start(); // Hay que usar variables de sesion para poder mantener el valor del ID de la compra
require_once("conexion.php");
$link = Conexion::getInstance();

if (isset($_POST['socios']) && isset($_POST['inicioCompra'])) { // He añadido la variable que llega de inicio.php para hacer la compra solo la 1ª vez que llego aqui
    $fecha = date("Y-m-d");
    $insert = "INSERT INTO compras (com_id,com_fecha,com_socio) VALUES (0, '$fecha', '".$_POST['socios']."')";
    mysqli_query($link, $insert);

    $id_compra = mysqli_insert_id($link);
    $_SESSION['idCompra'] = $id_compra; // Almacenamos en esta variable de sesion el ID de la compra para tenerlo cada vez que añadamos un libro
}

// Añado este if para saber que lo que quiero es añadir un libro a la tabla Detalles
if (isset($_POST['anadoLibro']) && isset($_POST['numero_de_libros'])){
    mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO detalles (det_cantidad,det_libro,det_compra) VALUES ($_POST[numero_de_libros],$_POST[add_libros],$_SESSION[idCompra])");
}
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $sql_borrar = "DELETE FROM detalles WHERE detalles.det_id =".$_GET['linea']."";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($link,$sql_borrar);
    echo "OK borrado";
}
```

[image: Código php]

```
while ($fila_libros = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_libros)) {
                                // En esta sección estamos llenando el select con datos extraidos de una base de datos.
                                echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>".$fila_libros['isbn']."</td>";
                                    echo "<td>".$fila_libros['titulo']."</td>";
                                    echo "<td>".$fila_libros['cantidad']."</td>";
                                    echo "<td class='text-center'><a href ='edicion.php?linea=$fila_libros[detID]'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></a></td>";
                                    echo "<td class='text-center'><a href ='detalles.php?linea=$fila_libros[detID]&delete=1'><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></></td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
```

***Gracias de antemano !!!!***

Comment: Hola. Estas pasando los datos vía get, por la dirección escrita a mano, y sin seguridad (p.ej. usar sentencias preparadas) de modo que te pueden hacer ataques de inyección sql. ¿Qué error te muestra al tratar de borrar? **Noto que:** `if(isset($_POST['delete'])){` **no se ejecuta** porque `<a href ='detalles.php?linea=$fila_libros[detID]&delete=1'>` invoca directamente la dirección. No espera a que haya submit de un form. Simplemente abre la dirección enlazada sin hacer post.

Answer (score -1):

Hola ya lo solucioné gracias.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la solución a la pregunta que realicé anteriormente gracias !
[image: Solcuión 1]

[image: Solcuión 1]